# Using not included items

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have `Visual c++` project that is using `boost` logging. In this project I have `unitA.cpp` and `unitA.h` that includes nothing from main project. According to my understanding I cannot use boost logging shown below in `unitA.cpp`:

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg,boost::log::trivial::debug)<<"value"
```

But real life is different - project compiles and runs fine and I can use boost logging in `unitA.cpp`. Where I get wrong in my understanding?

Comment: What *do* you include?

Comment: I have included boost in other units of my project

Comment: You have a source file, which includes some header files, which in turn include other header files and so on. Somewhere in this chain you include the Boost log header files, otherwise you would get an error.